# Q: Firestore security rules - where stored?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Noob question on Firestore Security Rules. Read the docs, not sure on this.

Can I have multiple security rules? I'm using the UI console for Firebase > Database > Rules

I see the editor, but I'm not sure, do they intend all rules to be put in this single document, or are there multiple documents each with a different rule? I expected to see a list of them I could edit.

There was a comment in one of the docs about updating in the UI console vs in a user directory. Is this referring to the virtual linux machine? I get into that via web based cloud shell and move around, but the home directory for my project is empty (except for the ReadMe) even after publishing a change to the rule in the Rules tab of the Firestore control panel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment all rules for a Firestore project are stored in a single file. Work is under way to allow multiple separate files, but at the moment you'll have to include everything in one file.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I have multiple security rules?

Yes, and the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations) shows examples of multiple rules.  Rules would be pretty useless without the ability to write more than one.

> There was a comment in one of the docs about updating in the UI console vs in a user directory. Is this referring to the virtual linux machine?

If you want to deploy from a local machine, it doesn't matter what you use.  You just have to be able to [run the Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/manage-deploy#use_the).

Comment: By multiple rules I'm asking if they are stored in multiple documents, or does the entire collection of rules go in this single doc? Thank you.

Comment: Security rules aren't stored like document data. Currently, they all go in the same text file, seen in the console in that dedicated tab.